# Best approach to load huge data into the UI

Tags: wpf, winforms, wcf

I am building a trading application and have to handle around 5 million rows in the UI using WPF. The data will be refreshed every now and then. We are thinking of using WCF as the service layer. What would be the best approach/control to handle such scenario, given the user demand of having a responsive UI most of the time ?

Technology-wise we are Microsoft shop. Another question would be, can WPF handle that large data or WinForms would be the way to go ?

Comment: How many rows at a time?

Comment: Why present 5M rows in the UI? What's the user supposed to do with so much data?

Comment: I edited out portions of your question that people who are helping strangers for free typically don't respond well to. You might want to keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: If you really need to display a lot of data then a paged data source is the way to go, but I'd seriously question the need to display that much data in one go.

Comment: Ok Jay thanks but...I just wanted to cut the crap.

Comment: This is such a common scenario to load that kind of data...why there is so many surprises ?

Answer (score 5):

You will want to use [Data Virtualization](http://www.slideshare.net/Cameroon45/data-virtualization-in-wpf-and-beyond) (note - not [UI Virtualization](http://www.kirupa.com/net/ui_virtualization_pg1.htm)), for which [this](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=344) is a very good jump-starter.

Comment: Links are down :(